# Image cannot be an array or an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a project which consists of publishing a post and being able to upload a user image. I used JS for Front and NodeJs for Back (Multer for uploading images).I have an error for making a post and uploading an image to my DDBB in Mysql.
I created the posts without any errors, but when I implement ability of sending an image I got this error:

> string violation: image cannot be an array or an object

Code:

```
//Here call the action from PostActions
const addPost = (body) => dispatch(createPostAction(body));

const userId = props.credentials?.user.id

//Formate the picture
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('image', image, userId);
const user = post.user;
const token = post.token;

//Create the post
addPost({
    title,
    content,
    image,
    userName: post.name,
    lastName: post.lastName,
    date: new Date(),
    userId: user.id,
    token: token,
});
```

```
//My route
router.post("/", authenticate, fileUpload, async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const id = req.body;
        const image = req.file;
        res.json(await postControllers.makePost(id, image))
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({
           message: error.message
        });
    }
});
```

```
//My controller
async makePost(post) {
    return Post.create(post);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend storing images in a mysql database, or any database in general.

The most common way to handle image uploads it to store an image into a file storage system like Amazon S3 or Cloudfront, and then store the image url you receive (which is usually the file path to the image, and is a string), in the database.

This is due to both performance and bandwidth optimization.

However, if you want to store it in your MySQL database, you need to store it as a blob. Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE 'test'.'pic' (
  'pic' INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'img' LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('pic')
)
```

This string violation could be due to MySQL expecting a string (path to an image), and is not configured to receive a blob type.

To test, try passing in a string as the value of the image key, and see if adding the post succeeds.